# Moisture sensor data will not output data to Serial Monitor?

Tags: sensors

I am making a Soil Analysis system with an Arduino Uno, but I have run into a problem and was wondering if /r/learnprogramming could help!

The moisture sensor section of my code will not output the data to the Serial Monitor in Arduino 1.7.1 IDE. I am not sure why it's not working. Running the moisture sensor code by itself works, and I just copied and pasted that code into my combined code file since I'll I am running 4 sensors at once with my Arduino Uno.

These are the four values I need to output data on one baud rate:

- pH value
- EC
- DHT temperature reading
- Moisture Sensor Value
  I am currently missing Moisture Sensor Value when I run Combined1.ino

Here is the Combined1.ino code of the code from four sensors together that's uploaded to the Arduino: 
[Combined Code Link](https://github.com/trooper5010/Soil-Analysis-System/blob/master/Combined1.ino)
[Moisture Sensor Link](https://github.com/trooper5010/Soil-Analysis-System/blob/master/Moisture_Sensor.ino)

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: /r/learnprogramming? Are we Reddit now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second print section will always fail.

You have:

```
if(millis() - printTime > printInterval)   //Every 800 milliseconds, print a numerical, convert the state of the LED indicator
```

However, a bit before then you have:

```
if(millis()-printTime>=printInterval)
{
  printTime=millis();
```

So `millis() - printTime` can never be greater than `printInterval` since you have just set `printTime` to `millis()`. So `millis() - printTime` will always be somewhere between `0` and `printInterval - 1`.

Consider combining your different printing routines into one single printing routine so you are comparing (and changing) the `printTime` only once.

Comment: I got it to work. There is something happening with the DHT22 section that when the DHT22 is not connected, it fails and ends the loop. I just moved my moisture sensor code above that and it is now working. I will see if I can clean it up using this advice.